# VBA: need to sort shapes

Tags: vba, excel

Recently, in an interview I encountered a question in VBA. The question is:

Write a program to sort the shapes in a worksheet, like for example : I have various shapes like circle, triangle, rectangle, pentagon... This needs to be sorted and placed one below the other. 
I tried with Shapes object and msoshapeRectangle method. But it didnt work.

Could you please tell me is this possible to be done?

Thanks

Comment: The `Worksheet.Shapes` collection exposes all of the `Shape` objects within a `Worksheet` and the `Shape` object exposes it's `TopLeftCell` and `BottomRightCell`. Using this, it would be very easy to arrange all of the shapes in a column.

Comment: You can tell what type of shape a Shape object is by referencing its `AutoShapeType` property.

Answer (score 0):

It was an interesting challenge, so I did it.  Might as well post the result (commented for clarity):

```
Sub tgr()

    'There are 184 total AutoShapeTypes
    'See here for full list
    'https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Office-Shared-VBA/articles/msoautoshapetype-enumeration-office
    Dim aShapeTypes(1 To 184) As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vShpName As Variant
    Dim dLeftAlign As Double
    Dim dTopAlign As Double
    Dim dVerticalInterval As Double
    Dim dHorizontalInterval As Double
    Dim dPadding As Double

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    'Sort order will be by the AutoShapeType numerical ID
    'Using this, shapes will be sorted in this order (incomplete list for brevity):
    '   Rectangle, Parallelogram, Trapezoid, Diamond, Rounded rectangle, Octagon, Isosceles triangle, Right triangle, Oval, Hexagon
    'Note that you can use a Select Case to order shapes to a more customized list
    'I use this method to put the -2 (indicates a combination of the other states) at the bottom of the sort order
    For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
        Select Case Shp.AutoShapeType
            Case -2:    aShapeTypes(UBound(aShapeTypes)) = aShapeTypes(UBound(aShapeTypes)) & "||" & Shp.Name
            Case Else:  aShapeTypes(Shp.AutoShapeType) = aShapeTypes(Shp.AutoShapeType) & "||" & Shp.Name
        End Select
    Next Shp

    'Now that all shapes have been collected and put into their sort order, perform the actual sort operation
    'Adjust the alignment and vertical veriables as desired
    'The Padding variable is so that the shapes don't start at the very edge of the sheet (can bet set to 0 if that's fine)
    'I have it currently set to sort the shapes vertically, but they can be sorted horizontally by uncommenting those lines and commenting out the vertical sort lines

    dPadding = 10
    dLeftAlign = 5
    dTopAlign = 5
    dVerticalInterval = 40
    dHorizontalInterval = 40

    j = 0
    For i = LBound(aShapeTypes) To UBound(aShapeTypes)
        If Len(aShapeTypes(i)) > 0 Then
            For Each vShpName In Split(Mid(aShapeTypes(i), 3), "||")
                With ws.Shapes(vShpName)

                    'Vertical Sort
                    .Left = dLeftAlign
                    .Top = j * dVerticalInterval + dPadding

                    'Horizont Sort
                    '.Top = dTopAlign
                    '.Left = j * dHorizontalInterval + dPadding

                End With
                j = j + 1
            Next vShpName
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of interview could possibly be asking for someone to write such a complicated (and somewhat useless program)? Nice job btw, tested and it works well!

Comment: @dwirony I agree, it's pretty strange.  I think the point of the question though is to force the programmer to think outside the box and adapt to a challenge they've likely never done before.  Possibly a good way to weed out those that simply can't code or those that give up before putting in enough thought to at least try to find a solution.

Comment: Very true. I gave it a shot but tapped out... I very rarely work with shapes in my line of excel work so I have no familiarity with any of the terms/types, I would've been out of contention!

Comment: If they wanted to look at speed and simplicity of finding a solution. Record macro and drag the shapes to desired locations. It will be a solution within 1 minute . Question is how it would be received haha

Comment: @tigeravatar... Thanks for this wonderful code... I tried this code by inserting shapes within Excel... Its working fine.. However, it is placing rectangle before triangle... I am not sure if I did something wrong...

Comment: @user3228901 As I specifically stated in my comments within the code:     `Sort order will be by the AutoShapeType numerical ID`, `Using this, shapes will be sorted in this order (incomplete list for brevity): Rectangle, Parallelogram, Trapezoid, Diamond, Rounded rectangle, Octagon, Isosceles triangle, Right triangle, Oval, Hexagon`

Comment: @user3228901 I also specifically stated this: `Note that you can use a Select Case to order shapes to a more customized list`.  I did not specifically put circles first, but that could easily be done.  I'll leave it to you to figure out how